# Tumblr Pagination not working on tagged posts

Tags: pagination, tags, tumblr

I am having problems with my tumblr pagination on tagged posts. Basically the best example  to illustrate the problem is to click http://ellecharie.com/tagged/fashion/page/4. Notice that the page is blank. However, http://ellecharie.com/tagged/fashion/page/7 page displays content. In fact this particular tag goes up to page 19 when the majority is blank content. Any help to fix this would be much appreciated.

Tag coding:

```
    <div class="blue">
     {block:HasTags}
      {block:Tags}
       <a href="http://ellecharie.com/tagged/{Tag}">#{Tag}</a>
      {/block:Tags}
     {/block:HasTags}
    </div>
```

Pagination coding:

```
{block:IndexPage}
<center>  <center>{block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}"><font size="30">&#171;</font></a>     {/block:NextPage}
{block:PreviousPage}  <a href="{PreviousPage}"><font size="20">&#187;</font></a>  {/block:PreviousPage}<br>
{block:PermalinkPagination}
{block:NextPost}<a href="{NextPost}"><font size="30">&#171;</font></a>{/block:NextPost}
{block:PreviousPost}  <a href="{PreviousPost}"><font size="30">&#187;</font></a>{/block:PreviousPost}
{/block:PermalinkPagination}<p>
</center>
{/block:IndexPage}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: I could be wrong but you seem to have alot of code that would normally be in the head of the document further down the body, and where I would expect to see tumblr code at the bottom, it appears higher up and your document code appears lower down, so I am wondering if there are some tags that are not closed properly, or you have a duplicate block of code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a server-end problem, not much you can do.
If you check the blog posts tagged fashion [via the API](http://ellecharie.com/api/read?tagged=fashion&num=50), you'll see a discrepancy from the 21st to 31st post.

Normally it should show posts 1-50 of of the total 152, but in this case there's nothing there.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with deleted or private posts, or maybe the posts are so old (from 2011) the tumblr servers have trouble recalling them. In any case, if it's a persistent issue you can try to contact tumblr support.

Comment: Well, for starters, the max you can request is 20 and "officially" speaking the V1 API is deprecated. However, I've checked with the V2 API and the regular paging, and neither is consistent. V2 only returned 13 posts of the supposed 153 total. It should be returning the first 20. So, chalking this up to another Tumblr Support problem that will likely never be fixed. However, I will report it.

Comment: Oh, I see now, they changed the max to 50. I wonder when they did that? I wonder if that change also ushered in some code that is causing the problems.

Comment: Yeah, the API v1 is deprecated, but I still use it to quickly debug things like this. You can pass in `num=50` (max 50) and `start=50` (offset from 50) url attributes to the API v1.